# iPhone payments

Tags: ios, two-step-authentication

My iPhone is not working right now but I need to change my iTunes payment method. Tried using another phone on my plan to change payment method but am unable to because Apple keeps sending the verification code to the phone that's not working. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

[According to Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204152), you should be able to use a Recovery Key:

> You'll also get a 14-character Recovery Key to print and keep in a safe place. Use your Recovery Key to regain access to your account if you ever lose access to your trusted devices or forget your password.

Or receive the code by SMS:

> You're required to verify at least one SMS-capable phone number for your account. You should consider verifying all SMS-capable phone numbers that you normally use with your iPhone or another mobile phone. You should also consider verifying an SMS-capable phone number used by someone close to you, such as a spouse or other family member. You can use this number if you're temporarily without access to your own devices.

[To send the code via SMS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204974):

> Get a text or phone call
>
> If you don’t have a trusted device handy, you can have a verification code sent to your trusted phone number as a text message or phone call.
>   - Click Didn't get a verification code on the sign in screen.
>   - Choose to have the code sent to your trusted phone number.
>   - You'll get a text message or phone call from Apple with your verification code.
>   - Enter the code on your other device to complete sign in.

If none of this options are available, you may be out of luck:

> Only you can reset your password, manage your trusted devices, or create a new Recovery Key. Apple Support can help you with other aspects of your service, but they aren't able to update or recover these three things for you. When you use two-step verification, you are responsible for:
>   - Remembering your password
>   - Keeping your trusted devices physically secure
>   - Keeping your Recovery Key in a safe place
>
> **If you lose access to two of these three items at the same time, you could be locked out of your Apple ID permanently.**

You can still go directly to Apple and ask them for an Account Recovery

> If you can’t sign in, reset your password, or receive verification codes, you can request account recovery to regain access to your account. Account recovery might take a few days or longer, depending on the specific account information you can provide to verify your identity.